# it's java code shows arithmetic exception in this code how could i resolve it?

Tags: java, algorithm, open-source, project

```
import java.util.*;

public class E53 {
  int l = 0;

  public int fact(int x) {
    if (x != 1) l = x * fact(x - 1);
    return l;
  }

  public static void main(String... s) {
    int count = 0;
    E53 e = new E53();

    for (int n = 23; n < 100; n++) {
      for (int r = 2; r + 1 < n; r++) {
        int c = (e.fact(n) / (e.fact(r) * e.fact(n - r)));
        if (c > 100000) count++;
        System.out.println(count);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are asking is quite unclear... Where does the so called *Arithmetic Exception* occurs?

Comment: Also: 99! will not fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Your factorial implementation is wrong. Don't use an instance variable (`l`) to store the result of that method.

Currently it returns 0, since when `x==1`, you return `l`, which is initialized to 0, so `fact(1)` returns 0, `fact(2) == 2 * fact(1) == 2 * 0 == 0` and also returns 0 and so on.

You don't need any variable inside the `fact` method :

```
public int fact(int x)
{   
    if(x>1)
         return x*fact(x-1);
    else
         return 1;
}
```

EDIT:

As commented by Peter and Andy, this change only fixes part of your problem, since calculating factorial for large integers is not possible when using the `int` type, which is limited to `2^31-1`. Using a `double` or `BigInteger` instead of `int` will allow your code to work for the entire range of numbers for which you are calculating the factorial.

Comment: but after using this it shows error

Comment: @avinashtiwari what error?

Comment: @avinashtiwari an `int` isn't large enough to store 99! ~= 9.332622e+155 try using `double` instead or `BigInteger`

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class E53
{ int l=0;

 public int fact(int x)
 { 
  if(x>1)
  return x*fact(x-1);
 else
  return 1;
 
 }
 public static void main(String...s)
 { int count=0;
  long c=0;
  E53 e=new E53();
  try
  {
   for(int n=23;n<100;n++)
   {
    for(int r=2;r<n;r++)
    { 
      c=e.fact(n)/(e.fact(r)*e.fact(n-r));
     
    }
    System.out.println(c);
    if(c>100000)
     count++;
     System.out.println(count);
   }
  }
  catch(Exception ea)
  {
   System.out.println("AI");
  }
  
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

To speed this up and simplify it.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public enum E35 {
    ; // no instances

    public static double fact(int n) {
        return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
    }

    public static double comb(int n, int r) {
        return n <= r ? 1 : n * comb(n - 1, r);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long count = IntStream.range(23, 100)
                .parallel()
                .mapToLong(n -> IntStream.range(2, n - 1)
                        .filter(r -> comb(n, r) / fact(n - r) > 1e5)
                        .count())
                .sum();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(count+" took "+time/1e3+" seconds");
    }
}
```

prints

```
4138 took 0.07 seconds
```

Comment: #peter i cant able to understand this code